# Get current logged-in user from external site

Tags: users

I have 2 sites, a WordPress site and an external php site (hosted on a subdomain, not in the same directory as WP).

I would like the external site to get the current logged in user id, in order to display the relevant data in the external site. If the user is not logged in, it will redirect to /wp-login before redirecting back to the external site.

Would love some advice on how shall I approach this issue.

Comment: Are you looking for something like SSO (singe-sign on)? alternatively, you can implement some redirection mechanism with post data from site 1 to site 2, where site 2 passes some token/data about the user.  If site2 is accessed without being redirected from site1, it won't work because it lacks the post data sent by site 1, after it verified authentication.

Comment: Yes. As a matter in fact, I am looking for a SSO system, but with the WP site as the login provider to my external site. However, I am unable to wrap my head around how to do that, and most resources online are to implement SSO in the WP site. 

I can not use the redirection mechanism as mentioned because the user will have multiple options to enter the site, not only through WP.

Comment: I am 100% sure I saw some SSO app  (or maybe a plugin) that delegates auth to WP. I don't remember the name sadly but maybe look for "oauth2-provider" or something like this in the WP plugins . You can also try to to search a bit for keycloack, or if you wanna do it the hard way, you can create your own login system in that external php app, and make that external app query the WP database, and simply put a "not member, sign up" that redirects the WP sign up form example: https://gist.github.com/markrickert/2304788

Comment: either way, you have to do some work on the PHP external app. Either make it query the WP database directly, or make it send the request via oauth and make it handle the returned auth token